# Make three different convex shapes with four polyiamonds, by hand. Five times

Tags: no-computers, tiling, polyiamond

To while away the endless holidays.

Start with the four polyiamonds in row one. Arrange them without gaps or overlaps (flipping/rotating allowed) in a convex shape. Repeat for two more convex shapes, all different. Make the same set of three convex shapes again with the polyiamonds in rows two through five. So you should end up with three convex shapes, each tiled five times, for fifteen puzzles.

[image]